# strange Math.sin behaviour

Tags: java, audio, trigonometry

I'm making a program that plays a sine wave varying in pitch and I'm dealing with something that i've never seen before: the program should play a sine wave from 220 hz to 0 hz, and I can see the frequency going from 220 to 0, but what I hear is a sine wave that goes from 220 to 0 and then back to 220.
I have no idea how this piece of code can do that

http://pastebin.com/HS36k7XJ (had to post it here because of screwed up layout)

(where t is the time in seconds and f the current frequency (which is calculated by a simple linear interpolation, which behaves properly))

Comment: Please show us more of your code.

Comment: added code. that's pretty much all the program for now

Comment: More code needed, some explanation as well. For instance, what's the expected result of this line of code? if you're expecting to get values between 0 and 220, your code should look something like this: **Math.abs(Math.sin(t * Math.PI * 2 * f) * 200)**

Comment: why the math.abs? it wouldn't be a sine wave anymore.

Comment: there isn't much to say about what it's supposed to do: it should play a sine wave pitching down from 220 to 0 hz lasting 1 second, but instead it plays it for 0.5 seconds and then goes back to 220 hz (pitching up)

Comment: I don't know about sine wave, but if you're intending to get values between 0 and 220 (and assuming that f is always positive), what is it to do when **sin** function produces values lower than zero? (bare with me if I'm not getting your problem right)

Comment: @0R10N What are you talking about? He needs to produce signal amplitudes given by sin(theta) for 0 <= theta < 360, at rates up to 220Hz. You are definitely not getting it. If you don't know about sine waves you don't know enough to comment.

Comment: @0R10N That suggestion is inaccurate, offensive, and irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I mean no offense. Already deleted the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scale `f` linearly down to zero. This means that the expression `t * Math.PI * 2` will be scaled back to zero as well. The value you pass to `sin()` goes from 0 initially (because t=0) to some positive value (because t>0 and f>0), back to 0 (because f=0).

Let's look at the values of `t * Math.PI * 2 * f` over time and the frequencies:

- At t=0, the value is 0 and will increase with speed 220
- At t=0.5, the value is 345 and will stop increasing
- At t=1, the value is 0 again and will decrease with speed -220

It's reversing it's direction because `t * Math.PI * 2` is multiplied by f, and f is getting smaller. This means the whole expression will become smaller as t approaches 1.

Try this code instead:

```
double ct = 0;
for (;;) {
      if(t>=1) break;
            //System.out.println(t+" "+e.getValueAt(t));
            for (int i = 0; i < buff.length; i++) {
                double f=lerp(fa,fb,t);
                buff[i] = (short) (Short.MAX_VALUE * 0.5 * Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * ct));
                toSoundCard[2 * i] = (byte) buff[i];
                toSoundCard[2 * i + 1] = (byte) (buff[i] >> 8);   //(i know i could avoid doing this)
                t += 1.0 / 44100.0;
                ct += f / 44100.0;
            }
            speaker.write(toSoundCard, 0, toSoundCard.length);
        }
```

Comment: doesn't work: goes from 220 to i have no idea (pitches up) and then back to 220 :(

Comment: Are you sure you tested exactly this code? Note the changed arguments of the `sin()` function. It sweeps from 220 Hz to 0 Hz on my machine.

Comment: i think it has something to do with the phase of the sine wave. could it be?

Comment: Worked for me, I put a `println()` after the `speaker.write()` and received this output: http://pastebin.com/pbVAU5Lt

Comment: I updated my answer, trying to explain it. In essence the value of `t * Math.PI * 2 * f` starts decreasing with increasing speed after t=0.5.